# как рисовать из одного потока в другом?

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть собственный таймер, созданный в другом потоке.

```
Timer::Timer(const std::chrono::milliseconds& interval,
    const std::function<void()>& task,
    bool singleShot)
    : mInterval(interval),
    mTask(task),
    mSingleShot(singleShot),
    mRunning(false)
{
}


void Timer::Start()
{
    Stop();

    mRunning = true;
    mThread = std::thread([this]
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mRunCondMutex);
                auto waitResult = mRunCondition.wait_for(lock, mInterval, [this] { return !mRunning; });
                if (mRunning && !waitResult)
                    mTask();
                if (mSingleShot)
                    mRunning = false;   
            }
        });
}
```

в GIF.cpp я создаю воспроизведение гиф анимации

```
GIF::GIF(LPCTSTR sFileName, HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    CurrentFrame = 0;
    gifBitmap = new Bitmap(sFileName);
    UINT count = gifBitmap->GetFrameDimensionsCount();
    GUID* pDimensionIDs = (GUID*)malloc(sizeof(GUID) * count);
    gifBitmap->GetFrameDimensionsList(pDimensionIDs, count);
    frameCount = gifBitmap->GetFrameCount(&pDimensionIDs[0]);
    //frameAray = (UINT*)malloc(frameCount);
    /*установить в frameAray DrawCachedBitmap, в деструкторе delete()*/
    free(pDimensionIDs);
    //std::cout<<"ff " << _msize(frameAray);
    
    
}

void GIF::draw(HDC g, UINT CurrentFrame)
{
    Graphics graphics(g);
    GUID guid = FrameDimensionTime;
    gifBitmap->SelectActiveFrame(&guid, CurrentFrame);
    /*выводить кадры*/
    //gifBitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);
    this->position.x = 50;
    this->position.y = 50;
    ::std::shared_ptr<::CachedBitmap> cbitmap = PNGLoader::createCachedBitmap(gifBitmap, g);
    graphics.DrawCachedBitmap(cbitmap.get(), position.x, position.y);
    ++CurrentFrame;
    if (CurrentFrame > frameCount) CurrentFrame = 0;
    std::cout << CurrentFrame << std::endl;
    //std::shared_ptr
    
}
void GIF::Play(Graphics* g, HDC hdc)
{
    Timer *mTimer = new Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(100), [&] 
        {
            ++CurrentFrame;
            this->draw(hdc, CurrentFrame);
            std::cout << hdc;
        }, false);
    mTimer->Start();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
splash = new GIF(L"resoureses/Sample.gif", hdc);
splash->draw(hdc, 20);
splash->Play(gt,hdc);
```

Но при рисовании в другом потоке, как я понимаю теряется hdc, если рисовать в одном потоке, то все хорошо. Как мне рисовать из одного потока в другом? Или можно вообще придумать альтернативу?

Comment: самое простое правило говорит - никогда не рисуй с двух потоков одновременно. Упрощенное - рисуй только с главного потока. Почему? да просто сама отрисовка - это куча всякой работы с подсистемами ОС и если эти запросы будут идти от двух потоков, все разломается. Если же отрисовка реально сложная, что нужен ещё один поток - можно рисовать в битмап, а потом его уже в главном потоке просто копировать. Но тут все равно нужна синхронизация.

Comment: @KoVadim а тогда как мне обратиться к основному потоку? я делал таймер, чтобы там менялись кадры, или может лучше вообще просто создать массив из кадров и потом их рисовать? но тогда все равно будет интересно, как нарисовать из таймера в основном потоке

Comment: так как это винапи, то рисовать нужно только в wm_paint. Код таймера подготавливает новый кадр и вызывает запрос на перерисовку (например, UpdateWindow(хендл-окна)) и теперь уже в wm_paint используя подготовленную битмапу, просто прорисовываем нужный кадр.

Вариант два - в WM_TIMER просто переключаем номера кадра, а в wm_paint просто рисуем текущий кадр.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо

Comment: Из другого потока можно эффективно рисовать с использованием directx.